# How to return/save values with void function in C?

Tags: c, function, return, return-value, void

I want to save value with void function. In C++ i did somewhat like this:

```
void func(int & a);

void func(int & a)
{
   int value;
   cin >> value;
   a = value;
}

int main()
{
   int x;
   func(x);
   cout << x;
   return 0;
}
```

How would this algorithm look like in C language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pointers:

```
void func(int *a)
{
   scanf("%d", a);
}

int main()
{
   int x;
   func(&x);
   printf("%d", x);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a pointer.

```
void func(int *a)
{
   int value;
   if (scanf("%d", &value) == 1)
      *a = value;
    else
      *a = 0; //well, we don't have anything good 
             //way to signal an error.
}
```